# Limit the form submission (5 request per day)

Tags: php, mysql

There is a problem and I really need a solution for this.

This is what I want to do and I cannot do in PHP, probably because I am new to php.

I want to be it that per day there will be only 5 requests that any user can send. If someone submit a form, it will show up that the limit for sent request is already done.

Can someone give me an idea in how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you identify your users? Are they logged in? Or do you use IPs? How is the form processed? What have you done so far? Also, show us some code!

Comment: I don't have any code for that(in how to limit the submission of request), my users were logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?php 

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $currDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $con = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "db");

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `submission_count` FROM TableName WHERE submitDate = {$current}");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($row['submission_count'] > 4) {
        // dont save submitted data
    } else {
        // save data
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I added a few more lines after the $result.

Comment: there has an error in your code..  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int

Comment: it still continues to save. what is the problem with the condition?

Comment: Hey lyrem11. I've updated my answer. please check it again.

Answer (score 2):

for every request make an entry in database and store the `date-time` and `count` of request sent by the user.

before sending/submitting the form check for the entry of the current date. If record found then check for the number of request made.

update the record `count` for every request.

Comment: can give me a sample code for that? query perhaps

Comment: do you know [tag:php] and [tag:mysql]?

Comment: slight for now,I'm a beginner

Comment: how do you submitting the form?